How to delete the files stored in Azure App Service storage using Azure Functions?
I have a RAG system that will fetch certain files from an external storage and push to an in-memory ChromaDB after converting them to embeddings. Now the files that can be fetched depends on the user. There will be a unique directory for individual user that persists the data for the this vector database. I am deploying this system using the Azure App service. My requirement is that a specific user's directory should be deleted within 72 hours if no further question is being asked by him or her. For the same, I plan to use Azure Functions Timer trigger that checks through the directory creation date once every 24 hours. Please let me know how I can access the App Service storage using Functions.
I tried using Blob storage for storing the data, but I'd like to store in within the App Service's memory.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Kudu API can be used to delete files or directory.
https://webappname.scm,azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/<path/to/directory>
Below code worked for me.
I used Http trigger to delete the Vivek directory in site/wwwroot.

Note :-

used ?recusive=true to delete all files inside the folder or directory.
username and password is available in publish profile.
`DefaultAzureCredential() from azure.identity can be used for credentials


function_app.py:
import azure.functions as func
import requests
import base64
import logging
import json

app = func.FunctionApp()


@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS, methods= ['get'])
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    app_name="flask9july"
    username="xxxxxxxxxx"
    password="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    try:
        kudu_api_url = f"https://{app_name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot"
        credentials = base64.b64encode(f"{username}:{password}".encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Basic {credentials}"
        }
        before_response = requests.get(kudu_api_url,headers=headers)
        before_status= before_response.status_code
        before_data = before_response.json()

        before_response_json = {
                    "data": before_data
                }
        #deleteting files or folders        
        delete = requests.delete(f"{kudu_api_url}/Vivek/?recursive=true",headers=headers)

        after_delete = requests.get(kudu_api_url,headers=headers)
        after_status= after_delete.status_code
        data = after_delete.json()

        after_data ={

            "data": data
        }
        return func.HttpResponse(f"before delete list: \n{json.dumps(before_response_json)} \n\nDeleted sucessfully \n\nAfter delete list: \n{json.dumps(after_data)}", mimetype="application/json", status_code=200)

    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Error: {str(e)}")

OUTPUT:



Folder Vivek is deleted


Thank you so much for the post. Will look into this from my end.
